# EditText Data to be displayed in a recycleview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, stickyrecycleview

I have a fragment which contains a EditText part and a send button 
I need to send the same text entered in EditText by pressing the send button to the RecycleView.
The text which I sent should be displayed above the edit text.

The design is like this :

[image]

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: Here are thousands of chat samples to help you. https://www.google.co.in/search?q=chat+sample+in+android&oq=chat+sample+&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.4479j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Did you search for this ?

Comment: On send button add this string into your list and call notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<Object> list;
RecycleAdapter recycleAdapter;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    Button send= rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    final EditText editText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            list.add(0,editText.getText().toString());
            recycleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayout.VERTICAL,true));
    recycleAdapter = new RecycleAdapter(getActivity(), list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleAdapter);

    return  rootView;
}
```